# Reducing time of app start up in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have prepared one app.

My app have splash screen with drawable animation.When app start up showing white screen(1 or 2 sec) and showing my splash animation. Some time animation not completed it is move to next screen.I think I have done some mistake my code is,

```
splashAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgAnim.getBackground();
        imgAnim.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                if ( splashAnimation != null ) 
                    splashAnimation.start();
              }
        });

        System.out.println("----------"+splashAnimation.getNumberOfFrames());

          for(int i = 0; i< splashAnimation.getNumberOfFrames();i++)
          {  
           totalDuration += splashAnimation.getDuration(i);  
          }  
          Timer timer = new Timer();  

       TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
       {  
           @Override  
           public void run() 
           {  
               splashAnimation.stop(); 
                    Message msg = new Message();
                     msg.arg1 = 1;
                     uiHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, Constants.ZOOM_ANIM_DELAY);

                     //zoomAnimation();
            }
        };  
       timer.schedule(timerTask, totalDuration);
```

How to reduce time of app start up?

Comment: what is the value of  totalDuration variable  ?